# round up datetime in formula editor

Tags: apex, workflow, formula-field

I want to convert the given datetime to nearest hour datetime.

For Ex 1: Given datetime is 5/15/2017 10:32 AM then I want to convert to 5/15/2017 11:00 AM

Ex 2:  Given datetime is 5/15/2017 10:21 AM then I want to convert to 5/15/2017 10:00 AM

I tried FLOOR, CEILING but those all requires numbers. But how can I with datetime.

And important thing is the return type should be in datetime.

Comment: While this may be possible with a formula, it would be much easier to do in Apex. Is there a particular reason why you want to use a formula here?

Comment: "Nearest half hour" for me means that both your examples would round to 10: **30** AM - what you have are "nearest hour"

Comment: @Oleksiy - updated the ask to Nearest Hour

Answer (score 1):

From Using Date and Date/Time in Forumlas Cheatsheet:

> Finding the Hour, Minute, or Second from a Date/Time To get the hour,
>   minute, and second from a Date/Time field as a numerical value, use
>   the following formulas where TZoffset is the difference between the
>   user’s time zone and GMT. 
>   For hour in 24–hour format:

```
VALUE( MID(TEXT( date/time - TZoffset ), 12, 2 ) )
```

> For hour in 12–hour format:

```
IF( OR( VALUE( MID( TEXT( date/time - TZoffset ), 12, 2 ) ) = 0,
   VALUE( MID( TEXT( date/time - TZoffset ), 12, 2 ) ) = 12 ), 12, 9
    VALUE( MID( TEXT( date/time - TZoffset ), 12, 2 )) 
    - IF( VALUE( MID( TEXT( date/time - TZoffset ), 12, 2 ) ) < 12, 0, 12 ))
```

> For minutes:

```
VALUE( MID( TEXT( date/time - TZoffset ), 15, 2 ) )
```

> For seconds:

```
VALUE( MID( TEXT( date/time - TZoffset ), 18, 2 ) )
```

> And, to get “AM” or “PM” as a string, use:

```
IF( VALUE( MID( TEXT( date/time - TZoffset ), 12, 2 ) ) < 12, "AM", "PM" )
```

From using the above, you should be able to take each portion you want to round using `Ceiling` to get the nearest hour and then reassemble it back into a Date/Time value.

**EDIT**

In response to comments:

`TZoffset` is the offset from Greenwich Mean Time (GMT). For example, if you're in the US Eastern Time Zone (New York), the offset from GMT is - 4 hrs. This is only relevant if you're trying to convert a local time to GMT. Salesforce stores all data in GMT. Since you're converting it back to the same time zone and format after manipulating it, the time zone shouldn't matter.

You provided this formula which has a mismatch of parens:

```
DATETIMEVALUE(TEXT(customDateTime__c +
   ((VALUE(TEXT(AttnSnoozeIntervalInHours__c)) *60)/1440))
```

If you just want the hour of customDateTime__c in 24 hour format, you just do the following:

```
VALUE( MID(TEXT(customDateTime__c, 12, 2 ) )
```

Now, here's where it's going to get tricky for you. What you *really* need to know is whether the minutes is *greater or less* than 30 minutes which you can do using the CEILING function.

From above,

```
CEILING(VALUE( MID( TEXT( customDateTime__c ), 15, 2 ) ) )
```

You'll still need to take into account what happens if results of the first formula = 23 and the results of the 2nd formula = 1. When that happens, you'll need to advance the date.

Comment: Could you please explain about TZoffset?.This is my formula in workflow field update  `DATETIMEVALUE(TEXT(customDateTime__c + ((VALUE(TEXT(AttnSnoozeIntervalInHours__c)) *60)/1440))`. I want to convert this DateTime to nearest hour Datetime.  `AttnSnoozeIntervalInHours__c` is just numeric value from 1 to 23.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the formula you need:

```
DATETIMEVALUE(
 LEFT(TEXT( DateTime__c ),11) /* date string */
 + LPAD(
   TEXT( VALUE( MID(TEXT( DateTime__c ),12,2) )
    + IF( VALUE(MID(TEXT( DateTime__c ),15,2)) > 29, 1, 0)
    ), 2, "0")
 + ":00:00Z"
)
```

Comment: This is a great formula, how could i adapt it to round the date/time to the nearest 15 minute period?

Comment: The following formula would do it: `DATETIMEVALUE(
 LEFT(TEXT( DateTime__c ),14)
 +
 CASE( ROUND(VALUE(MID(TEXT( DateTime__c ),15,2))/15,0),
  1, '15',
  2, '30',
  3, '45',
 '00')
 + ':00Z'
)
+ IF( ROUND(VALUE(MID(TEXT( DateTime__c ),15,2))/15,0) = 4, 1/24, 0)`

Comment: @Lachlan, see above