Convert Created Date/Time with rounding time
I want to convert the given datetime to nearest hour time.
For Ex 1: Given datetime is 5/15/2017 10:42 AM then I want to convert to 5/15/2017 10:30 AM
And important thing is the return type should be in time.
Tired this:
TEXT(
    TIMEVALUE(
        DATETIMEVALUE(
            TEXT(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)) + " " + 
            TEXT(
                FLOOR(
                    (VALUE(TEXT(TIMEVALUE(CreatedDate))) - 0) * 24 * 60 / 30) * 30 / 1440
                )
            )
        )
    )
)


Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Please [edit] your post to describe the results you get, the troubleshooting you have done , any specific errors you have received.

This question is about rounding up but you could take it and modify for going down: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174338/round-up-datetime-in-formula-editor
